# Can't convert table value to string in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to loop over data in an SQL table, but when I'm trying to use the value inside a foreach loop action using the @item() i get the error:

"Failed to convert the value in 'table' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct."

So the row value can't be converted to a string.
Could that be my problem? and if so, what can I do about it?

Here is the pipeline:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried giving 'Entities'(SQL table name)in the lookup and '@item().tablename' in copy activity inside ForEach or in OData dataset itself.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Drop a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the above scenario with SQL table containing table names  in lookup and csv files from ADLS gen2 in copy activity and got the same error.

[image]

The above error arises when we gave the lookup output array items directly into a string parameter inside ForEach.

If we look at the below lookup output,

[image]

The above value array is not a normal array, it is an array of objects. So, `@item()` in 1st iteration of ForEach means one object  `{ "tablename": "sample1.csv" }`. But our parameter expects a string value and that's why it is giving the above error.

To resolve this, give `@item().tablename` which will give our table names in every iteration inside ForEach.

**My repro for your reference:**

[image]

I have given same in sink also and this is my output.

**Pipeline Execution**

[image]

**Copied data in target**

[image]